# Rails 4 Class includes ActiveModel::Model but does not define 'all method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, activemodel

I am using ActiveModel::Model so that a custom class can be used with simple_form. However, the 'all' method is undefined, and throws an error during an *Update*.

This example duplicates the problem:

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
end

MyModel.all
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for MyModel:Class

How can I add the 'all' method to my custom class?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `#all` is part of `ActiveRecord::Base`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/all/class

`ActiveModel` does not have an `.all` method

Answer (score 0):

Agush is right -- the all() method is part of ActiveRecord::Base.

I ultimately fixed my problem by re-working the controller to avoid the calls that led to MyModel.all() being called.